# How To Run Cron Job In Spring

Tags: java, spring

I have created a class ApplicationDataScheduler in spring which has a method reportGenerator with @Scheduled annotation. This method generates report in form of an excel which has data from a table. So, the class ApplicationDataScheduler and method reportGenerator, they both are showing with light grey colour in intelliJ saying class is never used and method is never used. Do I need to declare them somewhere or call them?
Following is the code:

```
    @Component 
public class ApplicationDataScheduler { 
@Autowired 
HibernateUtils hibernateUtils; 
 
@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * *") 
public void reportGenerator() throws IOException { 
List<Application> applications = hibernateUtils.getAllEntities(Application.class); 
XSSFWorkbook exportedData = convertToExcel(applications); 
FileOutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(new File("Applications.xlsx")); 
exportedData.write(output); 
output.close(); 
} 
 
private XSSFWorkbook convertToExcel(List<Application> applications) { 
XSSFWorkbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(); 
XSSFSheet sheet = workbook.createSheet("applications_data"); 
int row_index = 0; 
for (Application app : applications) { 
XSSFRow row = sheet.createRow(row_index++); 
fill_row(app, row); 
} 
return workbook; 
} 
 
private void fill_row(Application app, XSSFRow row) { 
XSSFCell cell = row.createCell(0); 
cell.setCellValue(app.getApplicationId()); 
 
cell = row.createCell(1); 
cell.setCellValue(app.getAppCode()); 
 
cell = row.createCell(2); 
cell.setCellValue(app.getApplicationSubmittedDate()); 
 
cell = row.createCell(3); 
cell.setCellValue(app.getRemarks()); 
 
cell = row.createCell(4); 
cell.setCellValue(app.getCreatedByUser()); 
 
cell = row.createCell(5); 
cell.setCellValue(app.getUpdatedByUser()); 
} 
}
```

Comment: Did you try adding @EnableScheduling on your main or configuration class?

Comment: @VaibS yes, that is added in main class already

Answer (score 0):

First, check it indeed doesn't run, because everthing looks fine. You can for example put `logger.info` somewhere in the scheduled task, and run your app. Regarding IntelliJ doesn't highlight your method, it's completely fine, because nothing from inside your own code runs it, it's being called from the spring framework.

Comment: yes, its not running actually , I added some print statements so its not getting executed. Is anything missing as its not running?

Comment: first, if you can unit test the `reportGenerator` it would be great. I also can recommend to change temporarly the `@Scheduled(cron = "0 0 0 * * *") ` with `@Scheduled(fixedDelay = 5000)` so you won't need to wait for midnight. Maybe it's running and the exception is not being exposed in the logs.